# App-to-User Notifications push to facebook from Postman

Tags: facebook-graph-api, postman

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/services/appnotifications

I try to make a push to my users who use my app, it is a mobile app. Is that possible?

I try first to get access_token when i POST in Postman

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=34563random354678&client_secret=3453456random5783456&grant_type=client_credentials
```

and after I post this with the access token I get above:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/47facebookUserToSendTo11/notifications?access_token="theAccessToken"&template=You have a message
```

and the and result is:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#200) Only web canvas apps can send app notifications",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 200,
    "fbtrace_id": "D3kjf/BNCjz"
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you solve this? I get the same in Postman